Pydantic v2 fail early
With the following example, I'd expect Root to fail early (after trying to validate sub_model_a, instead, it fails in sub_model_b, I've tried looking at the documentation but can't seem to find a flag for it, I think in pydantic v1 this would fail early?
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
from typing import Literal


class SubModelA(BaseModel):
    string: Literal['a', 'b', 'c']


class SubModelB(BaseModel):
    integer: int


class Root(BaseModel):
    sub_model_a: SubModelA
    sub_model_b: SubModelB

    @field_validator('sub_model_b')
    @classmethod
    def validate_sub_model_b(cls, value, info):
        validated_a = info.data['sub_model_a']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = {
        'sub_model_a': {
            'string': 'invalid'
        },
        'sub_model_b': {
            'integer': 5
        }
    }

    y = Root(**x)


If this is debugged, you can see we reach the validator, whereas if you try to instantiate SubModelA with the same value invalid, it would throw an expected error

You are trying to access a field that is not present in FieldValidation.data.
In the latest docs version you can see that the value of other fields can or cannot be present, so you must pay attention to this:

If you want to access values from another field inside a
@field_validator, this may be possible using ValidationInfo.data,
which is a dict of field name to field value. Validation is done in
the order fields are defined, so you have to be careful when using
ValidationInfo.data to not access a field that has not yet been
validated/populated...

But despite your code, I think that what is going on with your example is pointed in an older version of the docs:

If validation fails on another field (or that field is missing) it
will not be included in values

I presume here that what is going on is that validation from sub_model_a has already failed, and it is not passed along to next validators.
So in your case, I would add a validation check to see if the field you want to access is present, as the docs recomend:
class SubModelA(BaseModel):
    string: Literal['a', 'b', 'c']


class SubModelB(BaseModel):
    integer: int


class Root(BaseModel):
    sub_model_a: SubModelA
    sub_model_b: SubModelB

    @field_validator('sub_model_b')
    @classmethod
    def validate_sub_model_b(cls, value, info):
        if "sub_model_a" in info.data:
            validated_a = info.data['sub_model_a']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = {
        'sub_model_a': {
            'string': 'invalid'
        },
        'sub_model_b': {
            'integer': 5
        }
    }

    y = Root(**x)

And you'll get the expected result:
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Root
sub_model_a.string
  Input should be 'a', 'b' or 'c' [type=literal_error, input_value='invalid', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/literal_error

But why passing objects intead of dicts works as expected?
class Root(BaseModel):
    sub_model_a: SubModelA
    sub_model_b: SubModelB

    @field_validator('sub_model_b')
    @classmethod
    def validate_sub_model_b(cls, value, info):
        validated_a = info.data['sub_model_a']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    y = Root(sub_model_a=SubModelA(string='invalid'), sub_model_b=SubModelB(integer=5))

It's simply because SubModelA is created before, and it fails before Root is even created. So validate_sub_model_b is never called.
